Models with upper case or mixed case names fail in consecutive runs when using dbt-sqlserver
I successfully ran the process the first time, but it failed on the second run. I’m using Python 3.12, dbt-core 1.7.18, and dbt-sqlserver 1.7.2. I tested it on Windows and success, but encountered an error when running on Linux. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
enter image description here
I have tried things like rewriting the is_incremental
